# Get the list of (x,y) point of a graphic

Tags: graphics, functions, data

I have a function like this:

```
E^(-t/0.001)*Cos[t] + E^(-t/0.01)*Cos[1000 t]
```

I used the code below as suggested in the forum to obtain the x,y values for points

```
data = Cases[Plot[Exp@(-1000 x)*Cos@ x + Exp@(-100 x)*Cos@ (1000 x), {x, 0, 0.1}], Line[data_] :> data, -4, 1][[1]]
```

However, it works (plotting back the list of number obtained I generete the original function) only when inside the exp functions I insert numbers such as (2, 3), (1000, 10) and so on, but not if I use (1000,100) or (10000, 1000) and so on. Can someone help me to understand what is the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The default [`PlotRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) can truncate the curve resulting in multiple lines.

```
plt = Plot[Exp[-1000 x]*Cos@x + Exp[-100 x]*Cos[1000 x], {x, 0, 0.1}]
```

[image]

Note that with the `PlotRange` truncated, there are multiple separate lines

```
ListLinePlot[
 Cases[plt, Line[data_] :> data, Infinity],
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

When the `PlotRange` does not truncate the curve, there is a single line

```
plt2 = Plot[Exp[-1000 x]*Cos@x + Exp[-100 x]*Cos[1000 x], {x, 0, 0.1}, 
  PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

The resulting single line can be displayed fully

```
ListLinePlot[
 Cases[plt2, Line[data_] :> data, Infinity],
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

or truncated by the `PlotRange`

```
ListLinePlot[
 Cases[plt2, Line[data_] :> data, Infinity]]
```

[image]